# Segmentation Fault when using pointer to iterate through array

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which I am using to iterate through an array that I created. However, one line is currently giving me a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int practice[] = {7, 2, 3, 3, 5};
  int *ip;
  int i = 0;

  *ip = practice[0]; //this is the line giving me problems

  for(; i < 5; ++i){
    printf("%d ", *ip);
    ++ip;
  }

  printf("\n\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I notice when I change the line: `*ip = practice[0]` to `ip = &(practice[0])` the code suddenly works. I am not sure why this happening as the first line seems just as logical as the second.

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid using *magical* numbers like `5` arbitrarily in your code. Whenever possible those should be either defined earlier as being related to `practice` (e.g. `int practice_size = 5`) or eliminated entirely by using something like `-1` to indicate list end.

Answer (score 5):

Since integer pointer `ip` is uninitialized it contains garbage value.
Now when you try to dereference it by `*ip` and try to assign a value to the memory location pointed by it, you get a segmentation fault.

You should first assign a valid address before dereferencing the pointer.

```
int *ip; 
ip = practice;
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here:

> *ip = practice[0];

Is that you are trying to assign an **integer** to a pointer variable.

The square brackets are C-language's way to access the actual data, not a reference of it.

Now, when you used the & sign,which is used to get the memory address of this data, this assigned the **address** of this data to your variable, which what it is exactly expecting.

If you wish to iterate over the array using the pointer instead of a loop, you may want to do this:

```
ip = practice;
```

This will assign the address of the first element in the array to your *ip* variable, allowing you to increment it inside your loop.

Comment: No, he's assigning an integer to an integer *through* a pointer which has not been initialized, and therefore points to some random location in memory.